# Javascript dynamic hash creation

Tags: javascript, hash

here is my working function. How to create dataObject dynamically? (let's assume that I know how many columns I have)
I tried dynamically create variables 'value+i' with eval function, but with no success.

```
    function parseCSV(rows){
        dataProvider = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            if (rows[i]) {                   
                var column = rows[i].split(","); 
                var date = someFunction(column[0]);
                var value1 = column[1];
                var value2 = column[2];
                var dataObject = {date:date, value1:value1, value2:value2};
                dataProvider.push(dataObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

thank U

Comment: I don't understand what you want it to do that it isn't already doing. You end up with an array of objects, each one corresponding to a row; how is that not good enough? Did you want an object holding objects instead? Could you show us the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Do you mean for dataProvider to be a global variable rather than declaring it locally and then returning it from the `parseCSV()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how many columns you have, but want to create an object full of valueX's:

```
var date = someFunction(column[0]);
var dataObject = {date: date};

for (var i=1; i < column.length; i++){
    dataObject['value' + i] = column[i];
}
```

Rather than using value1, ... you should try to use more descriptive names, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

There are few approaches.

First:

```
var hash = new object();
hash["date"] = date;
hash["value1"] = value1;
hash["value2"] = value2;
```

Second:

```
var hash = {};
hash["date"] = date;
hash["value1"] = value1;
hash["value2"] = value2;
```

Third:

```
var hash = {"date" : date, "value1" : value1, "value2" : value2};
```

Comment: And don't forget simply `hash.myNewValue = 42;`

Comment: hash should be created anyway before. using variables before declaring em is a bad practice.